# Cannot acces Asp.Net Core on local Docker Container

Tags: asp.net, docker

I've created a app in asp.net core and create a dockerfile to generate a local image and run it.

```
FROM microsoft/dotnet:latest

COPY . /app

WORKDIR /app

RUN ["dotnet", "restore"]

RUN ["dotnet", "build"]

EXPOSE 5000/tcp

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://0.0.0.0:5000"]
```

Then, I've builded my image with the following command

```
docker build -t jedidocker/first .
```

Then, I've created a container with the following command

```
docker run -t -d -p 5000:5000 jedidocker/first
```

But when I run the following url into my host browser

```
http://localhost:5000/
```

I have an `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE`

is it a network problem? How can I solve it?

P.S: My windows version is 10.0.10586

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had the same issue and found the solution to this. You will need to change the default listening hostname. By default, the app will listen to the localhost, ignoring any incoming requests from outside the container. Change your code in `program.cs` to listen for all incoming calls:

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

More info:

https://medium.com/trafi-tech-beat/running-net-core-on-docker-c438889eb5a#.hwhoak2c0

Make sure you are running the container with the `-p` flag with the port binding.

```
docker run -p 5000:5000 <containerid>
```

At the time of this writing, it seems that the

```
EXPOSE 5000:5000
```

command does not have the same effect as the `-p` command. I haven't had real success with -P (upper case) either.

Edit 8/28/2016:

One thing to note. If you are using docker compose with the -d (detached) mode, it may take a little while for the `dotnet run` command to launch the server. Until it's done executing the command (and any other before it), you will receive `ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE` in `Chrome`.

Comment: It works! Just increasing answer details, usually, when you create an app, this setting is set to `http://localhost:8080` or something like it. It works well in a local environment, but, if you, like mine, is trying to run it from a docker container, localhost is another machine (inside container), so, you have to accept all requests outside or set it to accept the host ip address (machine running docker engine).
So, open it to web, use `*:port` :)

Comment: That only works if you're only going to run the app locally in docker, because the port number is hard-coded and is not the same for the other profiles defined in `launchSettings.json`

Answer (score 8):

Just update your entry point as follows, no code change is required:

```
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "run", "--server.urls", "http://*:5000"]
```

The default Docker network on Windows Server 2016 is NAT, so you may want to use the IP which you can find out with `docker inspect <container name/ID>`. Not sure if this is the case with other Windows versions as well.

Comment: Balint, could you explain why this works? It fixed my problem, but I'm not sure I understand why.

Comment: @tylerjgarland it will make dotnet listen on all IP addresses (interfaces) not just localhost (loopback)

Comment: As of May 2018 VS2017 Preview sends this information as an environment variable: `-e "ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80" -e "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT=44341"`

Answer (score 4):

Here's what worked for me in ASP.NET 3.1

On the Dockerfile You need to specify the ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS

```
ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS http://*:5000
```

then EXPOSE the PORT

```
EXPOSE 5000
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `HostUrl` as an enviroment variable

`appsettings.json`

```
{
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "Debug": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Warning"
      }
    }
  },
  "HostUrl": "http://*:8080"
}
```

`program.cs`

```
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var hosturl = configuration.GetSection("HostUrl").Value;
        var host = new WebHostBuilder()
            .UseKestrel()
            .UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
            .UseUrls(hosturl)
            .UseIISIntegration()
            .UseStartup<Startup>()
            .Build();

        host.Run();
    }
}
```

Then, you can override HostUrl as an environment argument on `docker run`

```
docker run --rm -it -e HostUrl="http://*:80" -e DOTNET_RUNNING_IN_CONTAINER=true -e ConnectionStrings__DefaultConnection="<your_connection>" -p 80:80 <containerid>
```

Open browser at `localhost` an be happy!