# AspNetCore App with Angular in Docker Container not responding

Tags: docker

I try to put a Asp.Net Core App with Angular in an docker container.

I build this example https://github.com/cschulc/AspNetCoreAngularDocker

I run:

```
dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish
```

after this I try to run the app from the publish directory with

```
dotnet DockerExample.dll
```

and it runs fine.

Now I use the DockerFile to build a DockerImage

Dockerfile

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443
WORKDIR /app
COPY ["/publish", "/app"]
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "DockerExample.dll"]
```

Command:

```
docker build -t dockerexample .
```

and run the container with

```
docker run dockerexample
```

the output is this

```
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.Repositories.FileSystemXmlRepository[60]
      Storing keys in a directory '/root/.aspnet/DataProtection-Keys' that may not be persisted outside of the container. Protected data will be unavailable when container is destroyed.
warn: Microsoft.AspNetCore.DataProtection.KeyManagement.XmlKeyManager[35]
      No XML encryptor configured. Key {6fda42c9-4247-47ec-b7b9-0b10d68b002e} may be persisted to storage in unencrypted form.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Now listening on: http://[::]:80
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Hosting environment: Production
info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime[0]
      Content root path: /app
```

But when I go to http://localhost I got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

I also tried

```
docker run -p 80:80 -p 443:443 dockerexample
```

but also got ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED

Can anyone help, please?

Comment: Have you tried connecting to the container directly? Usually it is something like 172.17.*.* when not tied to a specific custom network. Also, I cannot replicate the error because I don't have the resources. My attempt strands on trying to copy /publish to /app.

Comment: Did you run dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish?
I tried it wiht IPAdress of the container but get an ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE

Comment: No I did not run that command, but I don't have a directory to copy-paste either, so I just skipped trying to reproduce.
Also, some googling on the specific error gave me this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39045735/cannot-acces-asp-net-core-on-local-docker-container

It seems logical. The program could be listening to the localhost only. Can you try out their solution?

Answer (score 1):

So I fixed it by change the content of Program.CreateHostBuilder to

```
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .Build();

            return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .UseConfiguration(config)
                .UseUrls("http://*:5000")
                .UseStartup<Startup>();
```

and remove the Line

```
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
```

from Startp.Configure